# Convert batch file for loop to shell script for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to convert a Batch File on a windows machine to a Bash script on a Linux one. I am having trouble with this line though:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set CDATE=%%c-%%b-%%a
```

Can anyone give me the equivalent shell line and maybe explain what is happening at this point:

```
"tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/- "
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does under Windows? If your problem is understanding the windows shell script you shouldn't really tag this problem with "bash" :-)

Comment: It takes every file in a folder and processes them through the rest of the script. I understand what it does under windows, I need an equivalent in bash, hence the tag :-)

Comment: This code output the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD and do not process any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
  CDATE=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: CDATE="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" actually ended up being the equivalent.